# Visualforce "File Upload" page not uploading all attachments

Tags: visualforce, upload

I have created the following visualforce page, but it's only "Saving" the last attachment on the list. I know I must be missing something simple in the code. Does anyone have a quick idea?

```
<apex:page standardController="Devotee__c" extensions="AttachmentUploadController">
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Install Note Photos"/>

  <apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Install Note Photos">

      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Save"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>

      <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block1">

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Antenna Connections" for="fileName"/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Browse" for="file"/>
          <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Modem Connenections" for="fileName"/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Browse" for="file"/>
          <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Antenna Perspective" for="fileName"/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Browse" for="file"/>
          <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Cable Run" for="fileName"/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Browse" for="file"/>
          <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Additional" for="fileName"/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Browse" for="file"/>
          <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Additional" for="fileName"/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Browse" for="file"/>
          <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It looks like you've bound all of your `inputFile`s to the same field in your controller. I'd make a list of custom classes in the controller, each of which had an attachment and a label. Then, you can use an `<apex:repeat>` in the Visualforce to show them

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same "attachment" object with 2 different apex:inputFile components: you should create at least another "attchment2" and use it in the second set of pageblocksectionitems